# Test code and validation rules

Tags: unit-test

I apologize again for a rookie question regarding test codes.

In my Validation Rule I am referring to the value of an Opportunity which in this case would be a grandparent to the record with the Validation Rule by doing this :

```
ISPICKVAL( Country_by_Country__r.Opportunity__r.Signed_contract_required__c,""),
```

In my test code I'm setting that field value of the Opportunity but the Validation Rule but I'm still getting the error when I run this test :

```
@isTest
private class testProjectInitiationTrigger {

    static testMethod void ProjectInitiationTriggerTest() {

        Account account = TestHelper.createAccount();
        Opportunity objOpp = TestHelper.createOpp(account);
        objOpp.Manager__c = objOpp.CreatedById;
        objOpp.Signed_contract_required__c = 'test';
        update objOpp;

        //this is the parent record being created
        Country_by_Country__c objC = TestHelper.createCBC(objOpp);
        objC.Current_Tvl_Mgmt_Supplier__c = 'Test Supplier';
        update objC;

        //this is the child record which the trigger will run off
        Project_Initiation_del__c oPI = new Project_Initiation_del__c();
        oPI.Name =  objC.Name;
        oPI.Country_by_Country__c = objC.Id;
        insert oPI;

        //this is the child record field which will initiate the post update trigger
        oPI.Initiate_Implementation__c = true;
        update oPI;
    }
}
```

For some reason the Validation Rule in the record which refers to that Opp field is still kicking off when the test code runs. Anybody have any ideas ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I hope this isn't the problem (since I would hope Salesforce would take this into consideration), but try setting the relationship explicitly. Something like:

```
@isTest
private class testProjectInitiationTrigger {

    static testMethod void ProjectInitiationTriggerTest() {

        Account account = TestHelper.createAccount();
        Opportunity objOpp = TestHelper.createOpp(account);
        objOpp.Manager__c = objOpp.CreatedById;
        objOpp.Signed_contract_required__c = 'test';
        update objOpp;

        //this is the parent record being created
        Country_by_Country__c objC = TestHelper.createCBC(objOpp);
        objC.Opportunity__r = objOpp;
        objC.Current_Tvl_Mgmt_Supplier__c = 'Test Supplier';
        update objC;

        //this is the child record which the trigger will run off
        Project_Initiation_del__c oPI = new Project_Initiation_del__c();
        oPI.Name =  objC.Name;
        oPI.Country_by_Country__c = objC.Id;
        opi.Country_by_Country__r = objC;
        insert oPI;

        //this is the child record field which will initiate the post update trigger
        oPI.Initiate_Implementation__c = true;
        update oPI;
    }
}
```

Notice how I set `objC.Opportunity__r = objOpp;` and `opi.Country_by_Country__r = objC;`

Comment: that seems to have worked in referring to the Opp. Thank you. One other question : Should this line work as well : objOpp.Manager__c = objOpp.CreatedById;

There is a validation rule running on the Manager__c field and for some reason it's still coming back even though I'm populating with that. Can I not use CreatedById in that situation ? Thanks again.

Comment: Try referencing objOpp.Manager__r = objOpp.CreatedBy? I am not sure to be honest. You need to set the relationship field with the __r because apparently in test cases it doesn't query the database back and set those values. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand exactly because there is no Manager__r. There is no relationship named Manager. All I want to do is just put a value into that field. I would think objOpp.CreatedByID would work. I'm actually using it in the parent record (not shown above). I'm just putting in objC.CreatedById; for a value in one of those fields and it's passing.

Thanks Jesse. You're always a great help. I really appreciate it.